# Alamofireの読み教えてください。

Tags: swift, alamofire, 英語

Alamofireってなんて発音するんですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

公式的な言及は探したところ見つかりませんでしたが、[Alamo](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Alamo) （アラモは地名だそうです） + [Fire](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Fire)で「アラモファイア」と読むのが良さそうです。